# Highchart is not working on Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highcharts

High chart is not working on chrome , while same chart works fine on Firefox.

```
function display()
{

     $(function () {
        $('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Showing Requested,Processed and Relayed status on '
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Domain wise Break Down'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Gmail', 'Yahoo', 'Rediff', 'Hotmail', 'Others'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Request/Relay Status',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            //tooltip: {
             //   valueSuffix: ' millions'
            //},
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                       // enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Relayed',
                data: [c111,c222,c333,c444,c555]
            }, {
                name: 'Processed',
                data: [c666,c777,c888,c999,c100]
            }, {
                name: 'Requested',
                data: [c110,c120,c130,c140,c150]
            }]
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Errors shown by chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined highcharts.js:24
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined exporting.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'highcharts' read_csv.php:67
```

this high chart works fine when I open it in firefox but it show above mentioned errors when I open it in IE and Chrome. Please suggest how can I overcome these errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem will happen if you are loading jQuery multiple times.

Try loading a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest).

Comment: If you have a link, post it here.

Comment: I had just rechecked and found no loading of jQuery multiple times....<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>....no brother I am working on local environment so no link for that

Comment: Which version of jquery?

Comment: version jQuery 1.10.2

Comment: just try with jquery 1.8.

Comment: its working now with the same jQuery 1.10.2 .. i had just downloaded again and replaced .. thank you for your help..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was stuck on this for a long time!